# Условии для head для каждой отдельной страницы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте господа Хешкодевцы! Есть шапка к-я инклудируется а там такой код например:

```
       <head>
           <?if($_SESSION['page'] == "1"){echo('
           <script src="/js/1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');}
           elseif($_SESSION['page'] == "2"){echo('
           <script src="/js/2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');}?>
        //и т.д.
       </head>
```

А на каждой странице которая инкдлудирует эту шапку, в начале после старта сессии и инклуда есть такой код например:

```
<?unset($_SESSION["page"]);$_SESSION["page"] = '1';?>
```

Не работает почему то, можете предложить вариант?

Comment: Ну как работает, допустим когда запускаю страницу "1", вижу скрипт "1" есть, но когда запускаю страницу "2" там не вижу скрипт "2" почему то здесь тоже скрипт "1", вот так?(

Comment: ОМГ...

----------------------

Ну хотя бы уже

    if(isset($_SESSION['page']))
    {
        echo('<script src="/js/'.$_SESSION['page'].'.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
    }

Зачем элсефить безконечно?

Comment: Охо, че то об этом не подумал:) Ща попрбую

Comment: Размер кода конечно сократилось, такая же ситуация, похоже "unset($_SESSION["page"]);" не работает

Comment: обратите внимания кода <?php    ?> без php может на сервере не работать 

Comment: вопрос закрыт, решил проблему